# Difference between "Up to you" and "As you want"

Tags: meaning, expressions

At first sight both expression can be used interchangeably.
I heard that "as you want" is sexually connotated (UK). Is it right?
As a consequence I have become reluctant to use "As you want" in the traditional sense of "whatever you want".

Comment: I've never heard such a connotation, but then I probably don't move in the relevant circles. To me "As you want" is not particularly idiomatic: I recognise "as you like" and (slightly literary) "as you wish".

Comment: "Whatever you want" would be idiomatic in the US, perhaps slightly more so than "as you like/wish".  "As you want" is kind of odd-sounding.

Comment: As a native US English speaker I'll say I've never heard of "as you want" having any sexual connotation.  "As you wish" has certain "Princess Bride" connotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"As you wish"** is better usage than **"As you want,"** but you have to be cautious, because "As you wish" can be construed as being sarcastic by the listener unless it is very carefully spoken. If you are speaking with a client, saying **"As you wish, sir!"** (or **"As you wish, madam."**) would lessen the likelihood of your response being misunderstood.

On the other hand, ***if you intend it to be sarcastic*,** then saying it with a flat tone and offering a weak smile will convey your disdain for the person.